# How to get server side code coverage for protractor tests

Tags: protractor, code-coverage

Is it possible to get server side code coverage using istanbul for protractor tests, the grunt-protractor-coverage plugin gives client side coverage and i assume the __ coverage __ object is from the client JS files.
If so how to get the node js server side coverage?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul/issues/574

This is very helpful for getting code coverage on server side code. Essentially:

1. `./node_modules/.bin/istanbul cover --handle-sigint  server.js` runs the server with istanbul. `--handle-signint` means it will generate the report once it is terminated.
2. In another terminal window, run your tests that hit the server (no need to instrument them).
3. Exit the process in the terminal running `server.js` (with control-C for example).
4. A report is generated in a folder called `coverage` in the main app folder.

So every time a line of code is hit on your server side code, it gets recorded. It's important to keep track of what your tests are actually covering. Unit tests will cover a lot, but end-to-end tests will most likely miss a lot of branches of code.

(Also if anyone has any info on how to do this if you have a mix of JS and coffee files, any help would be greatly appreciated!_